# Jump to next line a neested column in bootstrap3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a problem dealing with nested columns in bootsrap 3. The thing is that I have a background image and a text floating to the right like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 test">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-6 col-md-6 col-md-offset-6 col-xs-12">
          <div class="description">
            <p>
              TEXT DESCRIPTION
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">sTART</button>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The test class is to added to have a background-image to that div.

```
.test {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url("../img/imgage.jpg");
}
```

What I want is to break to a new line when displayed on a mobile screen the nested column that contains the TEXT DESCRIPTION; more precisely this part of code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-6 col-md-6 col-md-offset-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="description">
      <p>
        TEXT DESCRIPTION
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Start</button>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So the TEXT DESCRIPTION jumps below the background image in a new line.
PS: I don't want to use the same code with two different divs and control the with the responsive utilities eg: `hidden-xs`.

Here is a link to the Plunker for what I did so far:
[Plunker code example](https://plnkr.co/edit/8efO1EtkC05iTlKntFmn?p=preview)

Comment: So you mean you need to TEXT DESCRIPTION and button will display in next line with the break?

Comment: use media Queries to handle this..

Comment: @JaykumarGondaliya, Yap I want it to be displayed after the column with the background image.

Comment: I create it a Plunker for it